# Склонение японских приставок к именам

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, если в тексте упоминается японское имя с вежливой частицей (или суффиксом - не знаю точно, чем это является) "-сан", то будет ли это "-сан" склоняться по падежам при склонении имени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обычно "сан" не склоняется** - и это безусловно правильно. Более того, будучи чуть-чуть знаком с японским если не языком, то этикетом, считаю возможным **использовать её при переводе только при обращении**, т.е. в форме именительного (звательного) падежа. Что исключает вообще всякие варианты склонения. Очень отдалённый перевод - "уважаемый Имярек Батькович". Вы не будете настаивать на использовании формы "уважаемый" в косвенных падежах? "Вчера видел уважаемого Ивана Ивановича"?

Впрочем, тут готов услышать возражения более знающих.

По грамматике. Это явно не частица. Насколько знаю, японисты считают её именно этикетным суффиксом, японский весь на таких суффиксах построен. А вот чем она является в русском, сказать трудно. Видимо её стоит считать чем-то наподобие служебной части имени, как, например, "-оглы" иди "-заде", хотя с совершенно другой функцией.

И ещё. Японские имена собственные вообще испытывают сильную тенденцию к несклоняемости. Что пока нормативным не является, но считаться приходится.

Answer (score 0):

По-разному. Зависит от того, женское имя или мужское, склоняемое или нет.